# Нужно ли обособление при неявном обращении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. — Надеюсь они сдохли(,) твари поганые!
2. — Ну держитесь(,) сукины дети!
3. — Да знаем мы их, — сказал Петр Палыч. — Скрылись уже, наверное, в своих ущельях(,) псы позорные.

Comment: Обращение тут только под номером два. И ещё добавлю, что нужна запятая и после *надеюсь.*

Comment: По поводу "надеюсь" - согласен, проморгал, пока примеры придумывал. А что по поводу остальных случаев? Там тоже запятые нужны?

Comment: Нужны, да. Но я не нашёл, как называются такие случаи. В последнем пропущено "они", которые псы позорные. Если бы это "они" не подразумевалось, тогда бы не нужно было запятой и "псы позорные" было бы подлежащим. Ну или просто "псы", дело не в этом. Но у вас явно не такой случай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Обособленное приложение, отнесенное **к личному местоимению** "они": *— Надеюсь **они** сдохли, **твари поганые**!*

Примечание: приложение обособляется в любой позиции относительно местоимения, в том числе при дистантном расположении.

2. Обособленное **обращение**: — *Ну держитесь, **сукины дети**!*
3. Обособленное приложение, отнесенное **к пропущенному слову** (личному местоимению "они"):
   *— Да знаем мы их, — сказал Петр Палыч. — Скрылись (**они**) уже, наверное, в своих ущельях(,) **псы позорные**.*

Правило: § 19. Обособленные приложения http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

п. 8. Всегда обособляется приложение **при личном местоимении**: Ему ли, карлику, тягаться с исполином? (П.);

п. 9. Обособляется приложение, которое относится **к отсутствующему слову** в данном предложении, если это слово подсказывается контекстом: *Ты держи его, держи, а то уйдёт, **анафема*** (Ч.; имеется в виду налим)...

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ.